# Step navigation with Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, viewchild

I need your help because I created a navigation step but I do not know how to use it. I use viewchild but it is unsuccessful for me. I also tried to create a function with an index++. There are three components to display on the same page. I don't know to do. I try different things with no result. But impossible to find something I want.

Watch the image below

Step nav image:
[image: Step nav image]

```js
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  public currentPage = 0;
  public changePage(change: number): void {
    this.currentPage += change;
  }

  thenBlock: TemplateRef<DragAndDropComponent>|null = null;
  show: boolean = true;
 
  @ViewChild('state')
  primaryBlock: TemplateRef<GridStateComponent>|null = null;
  @ViewChild('synthese')
  secondaryBlock: TemplateRef<GridSyntheseComponent>|null = null;

  constructor(private router: Router, private location: Location) { }

  ngOnInit() {


  }


}
```

```html
 <section class="main__container--step">
    <!-- Header & Switch -->
    <header class="mg--lg">
        <div class="flex flex--jcsb flex--aic">
            <h2 class="title title--sm title--grey title--uppercase">Configure Grid</h2>
            <form class="switchToggle flex flex--jcsb flex--aic">
                <label class="flex flex--aic" for="configure" #configure>
                    <input type="radio" name="switchtoggle" id="configure" value="configure">
                    <span><a routerLink="configure" routerLinkActive="active" ></a>Configure</span>
                </label>
                <label class="flex flex--aic" for="grid" #state>
                    <input type="radio" name="switchtoggle" id="grid" value="grid" checked="checked">
                    <span><a routerLink="state" routerLinkActive="active" ></a>Grid State</span>
                </label>
                <label class="flex flex--aic" for="synthesis" #synthese>
                    <input type="radio" name="switchtoggle" id="synthesis" value="synthesis">
                    <span><a routerLink="synthese" routerLinkActive="active" ></a>Synthesis</span>
                </label>
            </form>
            <button class="button__step" (click)="continue()" ><a href="#">Continue</a></button>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- End Header & Switch -->
    <!-- End Main Content -->
</section>
```

Comment: I can't see three components in the html snippet. But I believe you should be doing good with just *ngIf or *ngSwitch usage. Have you tried that is you dont need url reference for your sections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need actual routing for these steps, you may use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` under the buttons;

lets say our html is kinda like that:

```
<div>
  <button [routerLink]="['', 'step-1']">Step 1</button>
  <button [routerLink]="['', 'step-2']">Step 2</button>
  <button [routerLink]="['', 'step-3']">Step 1</button>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

then your routing file should be quite similar to this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: StepParentComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'step-1', component: StepOneComponent },
      { path: 'step-2', component: StepTwoComponent },
      { path: 'step-3', component: StepThreeComponent },
    ]
 }
];
```

and then use them inside your routing declaration inside your module(app or other, in case if that's not root module - use `.forChild(routes)`):

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the tabs of Angular materials but you can also make something like this with *ngIf:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="Configure">
    <ConfigureComponent></ConfigureComponent>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Grid State">
    <GridStateComponent></GridStateComponent>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Synthesis">
    <SynthesisComponent></SynthesisComponent>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```